# Unable to make textbox and button in line

Tags: html, css, razor

I am trying to place the button baside the textbox in a razor form but I am not able to get it properly aligned.

Here's my code :

```
<div class="row form-inline">
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.Product.description, "Product")
                    <span class="tt-container input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon"><i class="fa fa-barcode" aria-hidden="true"></i></span>
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Product.description, new { @class = "form-control", data_rule_validProduct = "true", @id = "product" })
                        <span><button type="button" id="addRow" class="btn btn-primary">ADD</button></span>
                    </span>

                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.Product.description)
                </div>
            </div>
```

I end up getting something like this:

[image]

Comment: have you tried to use `vertical-align: middle`. Please add relevant CSS

Comment: There is no css associated with this html.

Comment: Well the html has classes from bootstrap so there is CSS. Also those classes can be changed by you to add or remove CSS

Comment: Yes what I meant is, there is no extra css added by me. It's just bootstrap. So, should I create a separate css file to add the code you suggested?

Comment: You can test CSS directly in the browser so no need to create a CSS file right away but if that help then yes you should. Just don't fiddle in the files of Bootstrap if you donwloaded them

Comment: try using Flexbox. https://codepen.io/dhavaljardosh/pen/PyGKZW?editors=1100, tried to replicate your example.

Comment: What about with razor syntax? That's where the difficulty lies.

Comment: can anyone help me using razor syntax?